# Click on one cell and highlight relevant cells

Tags: excel, mapping, vba

What I'm trying to do is have a list of model numbers and next to the list is a list of part numbers for all models. What I want to be able to do is click on a model and have the parts that are in that model highlighted or some change to them to make them stand out. I assume there's a tedious way of me setting this up by mapping out the parts in each model but once that is done, referencing them should be easy. If possible I'd also like to go backwards with the lists. As in if I clicked on a part number it would highlight what models that particular part is in. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you written any code at all? If so, please post it. It's difficult to work with nothing but an idea you had.

Comment: No I have no code unfortunately, I haven't done much coding in Excel and don't fully understand its methods and such

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a basic example.

[image: Demo]

Here are the named ranges (you can just replace them with the direct reference if you want)

Example: Change `Range("PartList")` to `Range("G2:G7")`

[image: Named Ranges]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Range("PartList").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
Range("A2:A4").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
If Target.CountLarge <> 1 Then Exit Sub
If Not Intersect(Target, [A2:A4]) Is Nothing Then
    Dim z, Finder
    For Each z In Intersect(Target.EntireRow, Range("ModelList"))
        Set Finder = Nothing
        Set Finder = Range("PartList").Find(z.Value, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not Finder Is Nothing Then Finder.Interior.Color = RGB(180, 230, 180)
    Next z
ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("PartList")) Is Nothing Then
    For Each z In Range("ModelList")
        'Continue would be nice but in this case we will just color it repeatedly
        If z.Value = Target.Value Then Cells(z.Row, "A").Interior.Color = RGB(180, 230, 180)
    Next z
End If
```

We create a part list and name it `PartList`

I also create a list of models and name their parts `ModelList`.

When we change selection, we clear the colors in our list.

If they click on only one cell...

If that cell is within our model range `A2:A4`, we search for all of the parts associated with that model and color them green.

If they click within our `PartList` range, we look through our model list and color column `A` green if the part is found.

Comment: That's perfect and has the idea I'm looking for. However, is there a way to do this without listing the parts next the model? I'm wanting to have just the two lists. Is there a way we could split this on 2 sheets? One like you have in your example and another that has just the two lists that show the highlighted parts?

Comment: Ok this is great. So now where do I implement this code?